# Issue with Loading function ,javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Error from console

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

I have a set of code that shows notification

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alertify.success("Success log message");
    return false;
});
```

I tested this code with an alert, and it loaded after the redirect but for some reason it doesn't load the `alertify.success` code.

I created a button to test this code using:

```
 $("#success").on( 'click', function () {
    reset();
    alertify.success("Success log message");
    return false;
});
```

This example works perfectly fine if I use it in the head of my page. Any idea what went wrong here?

This is the script that is loaded ,  alert("Success"); works with the other stuff commented out

```
<script>
    alert("Success");
    function reset () {
        $("#toggleCSS").attr("href", "{{asset('assets/css/alertify.default.css')}});
        alertify.set({
            labels : {
                ok     : "OK",
                cancel : "Cancel"
            },
            delay : 5000,
            buttonReverse : false,
            buttonFocus   : "ok"
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
reset();
alertify.success("Success log message");
return false;
});


</script>
```

Comment: What does `reset()` do?

Comment: Where do you link Alertify library? Are you sure it is accessible in both pieces of code?

Comment: _"the redirect"_? What redirect?

Comment: Also, you don't need & shouldn't have a `return false` in your document.ready

Comment: @wumm it's a notification js for bootstrap. The files are loaded like i said it works well with a on.click

Comment: @epascarello SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Comment: Remove " on ...attr("href", "{{asset('assets/css/alertify.default.css')}}");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `"` in this line:

```
$("#toggleCSS").attr("href", "{{asset('assets/css/alertify.default.css')}}");
                                                                          ^
```

Comment: ReferenceError: $ is not defined
$(document).ready(function () { , any idea how i can fix that too?

Comment: Have you included jQuery?